# Expectation of function of random variables

Tags: probability, covariance, expected-value

I have two independent random variables, X and Y. U and V are defined as U=X+Y and V=XY. I need to find Covariance. I know, E(U)= E(X)+E(Y) and E(V)=E(XY)=E(X)E(Y). But how to write E(UV) in terms of E(X) and E(Y). Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Find $UV$ and use independence of $X,Y$.

Comment: Could you write the expression, please

Comment: Why can't you write down $UV$ and take the expectation of that quantity?

Comment: I wanted to write expression from definition itself. I had a confusion regarding it

Answer (score 0):

Note that
$$
VU=XY(X+Y)=X^2Y+XY^2
$$
aso
$$
EUV=EX^2Y+EXY^2
$$
by linearity and
$$
EX^2Y=EX^2EY; \quad EXY^2=EXEY^2
$$
since $X, Y$ are independent and functions of independent random variables are independent.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Can you clarify one more thing: we have $E(XY)=\sum_x\sum_y xy f_X f_Y $. How can we write E(UV) in this form in terms of X and Y. Would it be: $E(UV)=\sum_u\sum_v uv f_U f_V=\sum_x\sum_y (x+y)xyf_{XY} $.